# How to build a no console executable script in python 3.5

Tags: package, pyinstaller, python-3.5, cx-freeze

I've tried using PyInstaller but with no luck. Would appreciate some help in building a no-console exe.

**EDIT**

In the script I am using a phantomJS and chrome drivers. I've built a system tray application for Windows. I am trying to make an exe out of the .py. Pyinstaller gives me an error about not being able to load python35 dll

Comment: Did you get an error? If so what? Please see: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, i get an error when i try to open the .exe. Error loading python35.dll